# All transaction pending a lot of time?

Tags: metamask, ethereumjs, pending-transactions

I wrote contract and deployed it on remix today but it takes over 5 min to confirm.And I tried to call function of deployed contract , but the transaction still takes several minutes and even I call transfer token from metamask, the transaction need unusual time to be confirmed.Anyone knows
what happened?Is it a problem of Ethereum?Ropsten?or my walletaddress?(I've tried two but same problem happened)...

Answer (score 2):

The network is very busy right now, resulting in higher gas prices. If you use a gas price that is too low, your transaction will take a lot longer to confirm. I recommend that you use [ETH Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info/) to see what gas price you should use.

You can read more about gas in general here: https://support.mycrypto.com/general-knowledge/ethereum-blockchain/what-is-gas

Comment: I've set my GasPrice up to 20Gwei but it still need lots of time pending... (I send the same transaction yesterday,too.It cost lower GasPrice and takes only seconds to confirm that transaction)

Comment: 20 Gwei is still relatively low currently. ETH Gas Station recommends a gas price of at least 45 Gwei for a transfer time of <30 minutes.

Comment: Feel like the problem is caused by Ropsten ,I tried Rinkeby and it's awesome.